# Magento 2.2.3 List all configurable's childs prices when the configurable's childs are out of stock

Tags: magento2, php, configurable-product, out-of-stock

For a configurable product, the following code will list the configurable's childs prices only for the childs that are in stock:

```
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {

    $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_children as $child){
        echo $child->getPrice();
    }

}
```

When all childs are out of stock, the code above will not show anything.

For a configurable product that has all its childs out of stock, i would need to list the prices of the childs.

Has someone faced the same situation? I'd love to hear about your ideas or contributions.

Comment: first of all, enable the out of stock product show on frontend.

Comment: But will that configuration display all out of stock products on category pages as well?

Comment: please create personal chat so we can discuss

Comment: Hi Raski; the configuration for displaying all out of stock products, does not have any effect on the above code, when all configurable childs are out of stock